# What is the smartest way to delay javascript process that need the DOM to be generated

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have to scroll automatically in an element of my html DOM. For now I needed to use two `setTimeout` function to handle the different ways this function will be called. So this code resolve my problems, but I find it pretty ugly.

```
app.ports.scrollingTo.subscribe(function(id){
    function scroller(id) {
        setTimeout(function() {
        var node = document.getElementById(id);
        if (node != null) {
            setTimeout(function() {
            node.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
            }, 10)
        }}, 10)}
    window.onload = scroller(id);
  })
```

Is there a better way to be sure that the DOM will be loaded before executing the delayed code ?

Comment: I guess you could use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to ensure that the element is there?

Comment: @Icepickle mutation observer only works if the element exists to begin with, in the case of adding it later, it will be problematic to use

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Well, you could observe a parent container of that element to solve that problem, I think I did that with my answer, but feel free to say that would be the wrong approach

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
 //your code
}
```

Comment: he literally did that in line 10 `window.onload = scroller(id);` i assume the content changes due to some scripts. Also this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: i actually don't have enough reputation ):

Comment: @AbdulAzeezOlanrewaju use [edit] to edit your answer, don't put code in comments

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski but `window.onload = scroller(id)` is *wrong* - you need to supply a function reference and `scroller(id)` *executes the function* returning `undefined` (implicit since there is no `return`) and assigning that as the `onload`. So...it executes the function *immediately* and doesn't delay anything until after the load has finished.

Comment: But @VLAZ wouldn't you be able to argue that it simply works by incident, because the code that is supplied works with a subscriber pattern, which I would assume means that it gets subscribed to after the load event completed, so it might as well not be there (in doesn't make a difference). Where as this answer would make a difference, because it got taken out of the subscribe pattern (implicitly)

Answer (score 0):

So you could do it using the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), provided you have an element you can observe before that.

In this sample, you can see I am observing the parent container till a node exists, and then I scroll it into view

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

function containerChanged( mutationsList, observer ) {
    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList' || mutation.type === 'subtree') {
            var node = document.getElementById('element10');
            if (node) {
              node.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
              observer.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
};

let count = 0;
let interval = setInterval(function() {
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.id = 'element' + (++count);
  el.innerHTML = 'I am element ' + el.id;
  container.appendChild( el );
  if (count > 15) {
    clearInterval( interval );
  }
}, 100);

const observer = new MutationObserver(containerChanged);
observer.observe( container, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

```css
#container {
  height: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: solid #a0a0a0 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```